# how can I add Mouseover in ng-option Tag

Tags: angularjs

I want to add toggle in select options but the options are dynamically fetch by ng-option at runtime.

```
<select
ng-model="myOption"
ng-options="value.id as value.label group by value.group for value in myOptions">
```

Comment: Is this in angularJS? Angular v2+ doesn't have ng-model, it uses `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Its version  AngularJS v1.2.13